# How to send http request for php webservices

Tags: android

I'm a newbie in android development. I have to integrate web service in my app but it doesn't work. can someone help me out to resolve it.

Following is the source code

```
public class Registration extends Activity {

EditText edfnm,edlnm,edmobile,edemail,edpass;
Button b1;
TextView tv1;
private DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
private HttpPost httppost;
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> lst;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
    edfnm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edfirst);
    edlnm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edlast);
    edmobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edmobile);
    edemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edemail);
    edpass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edpass);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost=new HttpPost("http://amwaveswellness.com/protocol_suggestion/webservice/register.php");

            lst=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first_name",edfnm.getText().toString()));
            lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("last_name",edlnm.getText().toString()));
            lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile",edmobile.getText().toString()));
            lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",edemail.getText().toString()));
            lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",edpass.getText().toString()));

            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(lst));
                new add_data().execute();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        class add_data extends AsyncTask<String, integer, String>{
            String jsonstring;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    HttpResponse httpresponse=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    jsonstring=EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return jsonstring;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            tv1.setText(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

When I run this code it returns`null` responce

Pl tell me what's going on and how to tackle it.

[API request sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AykPd.png)

Comment: I suggest you to use OkHttp library. With this library, Http requests require less efforts.

Comment: Use Volley for asynchronous server connection

Comment: try this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Put all HttpClient and HttpPost code in doInBackground. Nothing in onClick.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example to achieve it.

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/

go through it.

Comment: i get respoce as { "success": "1", "message": "All Symptoms of the Neck", "symptoms_data":[ { "id": "68", "parts_name": "Neck Pain & Stiffness", "description": "Neck Pain & Stiffness", "symptoms": "2", "image": "upload/1490950482.jpg", "status": "1", "created": "2017-03-31 14:24:41", "updated": "2017-04-08 17:24:24" }, then how to peint message from this